# how do i change the direction the fingers bend with the scale?

Tags: rigging, bones

When I scale the fingers to bend only the pinky is bending the right direction, how do I change this?

[image]

Comment: you need to bend the finger bones a bit in their natural direction to the floor. This way the IK constraints know in which direction the finger should bend. Basically, it's the same as with elbows and knees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the rotation of the bones, in edit mode select the parent bone of one of the fingers, in the N panel adjust the roll by adding 180 to it,

[image]

then select all the finger bones including the parents of the other fingers, and press shift +N > Activate Bone to copy the roll. (don't forget to activate the last three layers of the rig before selecting the bones)

[image]

Here a [Video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9FKF.jpg) with de process